# How to check if date is today or yetsterday or return date?

Tags: javascript

How can i check if input date is Today, Yesterday or just return the date if it's noone of them?

I was trying to do the following:

```js
    const checkDate = (someDate) => {
      const today = new Date();
      let date = new Date(someDate);
      today.setHours(0);
      today.setMinutes(0);
      today.setSeconds(0);
      return date.getTime() === today.getTime() ? "Oggi" : date.getTime() === today.setDay(-1) ? "Ieri" : "Il" + date;
    }
    
    console.log(checkDate("December 17, 1995 03:24:00"));
```

Where "Oggi" is Today and "Ieri" is Yesterday..

Comment: @Daan nop i just edited it manually and mismatched today

Comment: `.setDay()` isn't valid syntax. Try using `setDate()`.

Comment: Are the dates `someDate` and `today` always created by machines in the same time zone?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and most probably the right way is to use some library. Try [day.js](https://day.js.org/docs/en/installation/node-js) - small, but features rich (similar to [Moment](https://momentjs.com/)).

To install:

```
npm install dayjs
```

Or CDN:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs@1.8.21/dayjs.min.js"></script>
```

And you are ready to use all the set of features:

```
const someDate = new Date(); // plain old JS date
const now = dayjs(); // same (current date) but with day.js

// of course you can do: dayjs(someDate)

// yesterday: you check if someDate is current date - 1 day
const isYesterday = dayjs(someDate).isSame(dayjs().subtract(1, 'day'))

// today: just check if some date is equal to current date
const isToday = dayjs(someDate).isSame(dayjs()); // dayjs() return current date 

// want to get back to plain old JS date
conat plainOldJsDate = dayjs('2019-01-25').toDate();
```

You can find more awesome features like parsing, manipulating, formatting, etc. in official [docs](https://day.js.org/docs/en/installation/installation).

Comment: on newer dayjs versions `isSame` should include a second parameter, in this case it should be `const isYesterday = dayjs(someDate).isSame(dayjs().subtract(1, 'day'), 'day')` https://day.js.org/docs/en/query/is-same

Answer (score 1):

Compare [`.toDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString) to check if a `Date()` is the same day:

```js
const checkDate = (someDate) => {

    // Create 'today' Date object
    const today = new Date();

    // Create 'someDate' Date object
    const date = new Date(someDate);

    // is Today
    if (date.toDateString() === today.toDateString()) {
        return 'today';
    }

    // Alter date to yesterday
    today.setDate(today.getDate() - 1);

    // is Yesterday
    if (date.toDateString() === today.toDateString()) {
        return 'yesterday';
    }

    // Fallback
    return 'fallback'
}

console.log(checkDate('1/4/2021'));  // today
console.log(checkDate('1/3/2021'));  // yesterday
console.log(checkDate('1/9/2021'));  // fallback
```

Answer (score 0):

isToday:

```
const isToday = (date) => {
    const today = new Date()
    return date.getDate() === today.getDate() &&
        date.getMonth() === today.getMonth() &&
        date.getFullYear() === today.getFullYear();
};
```

isYesterday:

```
const isYesterday = (date) => {
    var yesterday= new Date();
    yesterday; //# => today
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
    yesterday; //# => yesterday

        return date.getDate() === yesterday.getDate() &&
            date.getMonth() === yesterday.getMonth() &&
            date.getFullYear() === yesterday.getFullYear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that i missed to set mills and setDay was invalid, solved by using `setDate(getDate() - 1)` and by setting mills to 0

Here is the final solution

```
const checkDate = (someDate) => {
  let today = new Date();
  let date = new Date(someDate);
  date = resetHours(date);
  today = resetHours(today);
  return date.getTime() === today.getTime() ? "Oggi" : date.getTime() === today.setDate(today.getDate() - 1) ? "Ieri" : "Il" + date;
}

const resetHours = (date) => {
  date.setHours(0);
  date.setMinutes(0);
  date.setSeconds(0);
  date.setMilliseconds(0);
  return date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the current date with a [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object, then compare.
The function receives strings in the form of `mm/dd/yyyy`.

```js
function checkDate(date) {
  // get today
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

  // parse into strings
  today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
  yesterday = mm + '/' + (dd-1) + '/' + yyyy;
  
  if (today == date) {
    return 'today';
  }
  if (today == yesterday) {
    return 'yesterday';
  }
  else {
    return date;
  }
}

var date = '01/04/2021';
console.log(checkDate(date));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const isSameDay = (a, b) => {
  return a.getFullYear() === b.getFullYear() &&
         a.getMonth() === b.getMonth() &&
         a.getDate()=== b.getDate();
}

const checkDate = (date) => {
  const today = new Date();
  const yesterday = new Date(Date.now() - 86400000); // 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

  if (isSameDay(today, date)) {
    return "Today";
  } else if (isSameDay(yesterday, date)) {
    return "Yesterday";
  } else {
     return date.toDateString();
  }
}

console.log(checkDate(new Date())); // "Today"
console.log(checkDate(new Date(Date.now() - 86400000))); // "Yesterday"
console.log(checkDate(new Date(Date.now() - 86400000 * 3))); // "Fri Jan 01 2021"
```

`Date` documentation in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)